# insert custom option from sql query

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql, query

I want to insert custom options for a product via sql query.
I tried with these queries:

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product_option ( sku, product_id, image_size_x, file_extension, option_id, image_size_y, sort_order, is_require, type, max_characters ) VALUES ( NULL, 24981, NULL, NULL, 944, NULL, 0, 1, 'drop_down', NULL );

INSERT INTO catalog_product_option_title ( option_title_id, option_id, store_id, title ) VALUES ( 944, 944, 0, 'NEW MODEL' );

INSERT INTO catalog_product_option_type_value ( option_type_id, sku, sort_order, option_id ) VALUES ( 3264, '00-13000381', 1, 944 );

INSERT INTO catalog_product_option_type_title ( option_type_id, 
option_type_title_id, store_id, title ) VALUES ( 3264, 3264, 0, '909 PLUS' );

INSERT INTO catalog_product_option_type_price ( option_type_id, price_type, price, option_type_price_id, store_id ) VALUES ( 3264, 'fixed', 0.0, 3264, 0 );
```

The option is not showed in the admin panel.
Am I missing some table?

Comment: Yes, you missed "catalog_product_option_price" table entry, please try to insert records in this table.

Comment: The table is empty and the options added from the admin panel are showed.

Comment: However doesn't work.